# Map a list of options to list of strings

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have the following function in OCaml:

```
let get_all_parents lst = 
  List.map (fun (name,opt) -> opt) lst
```

That maps my big list with `(name, opt)` to just a list of `opt`. An option can contain of either `None` or `Some value` which in this case is a string. I want a list of **strings** with all my values.

I am a beginner learning OCaml.

Comment: search for `List.filter` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `filter` and `map` used together is a good solution to this problem. This is because when you apply `map` to convert your `string option` to `string`, you will have the `None` case to deal with. Even if *you* know that you won't have any `None`s because you `filter`ed them away, the type checker doesn't, and can't help you. If you have non-exhaustive pattern match warnings enabled, you will get them, or you will have to supply some kind of dummy string for the `None` case. And, you will have to *hope* you don't introduce errors when refactoring later, or else write test cases or do more code review.

Instead, you need a function `filter_map : ('a -> 'b option) -> 'a list -> 'b list`. The idea is that this works like `map`, except `filter_map f lst` drops each element of `lst` for which `f` evaluates to `None`. If `f` evaluates to `Some v`, the result list will have `v`. You could then use `filter_map` like so:

```
filter_map (fun (_, opt) -> opt) lst
```

You could also write that as

```
filter_map snd lst
```

A more general example would be:

```
filter_map (fun (_, opt) ->
  match opt with
  | Some s -> Some (s ^ "\n")
  | None -> None)
  lst
```

`filter_map` can be implemented like this:

```
let filter_map f lst =
  let rec loop acc = function
    | []      -> List.rev acc
    | v::lst' ->
      match f v with
      | None    -> loop acc lst'
      | Some v' -> loop (v'::acc) lst'
  in

  loop [] lst
```

**EDIT** For greater completeness, you could also do

```
let filter_map f lst =
  List.fold_left (fun acc v ->
    match f v with
    | Some v' -> v'::acc
    | None    -> acc) [] lst
  |> List.rev
```

It's a shame that this kind of function isn't in the standard library. It's present in both [Batteries Included](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc/BatList.html) and [Jane Street Core](http://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/108.07.01/doc/core/List.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to expand on @Carsten's answer. He is pointing you the right direction.

It's not clear what question you're asking. For example, I'm not sure why you're telling us about your function `get_all_parents`. Possibly this function was your attempt to get the answer you want, and that it's not quite working for you. Or maybe you're happy with this function, but you want to do some further processing on its results?

Either way, `List.map` can't do the whole job because it always returns a list of the same length as its input. But you need a list that can be different lengths, depending on how many `None` values there are in the big list.

So you need a function that can extract only the parts of a list that you're interested in. As @Carsten says, the key function for this is `List.filter`.

Some combination of `map` and `filter` will definitely do what you want. Or you can just use `fold`, which has the power of both `map` and `filter`. Or you can write your own recursive function that does all the work.

**Update**

Maybe your problem is in extracting the `string` from a `string option`. The "nice" way to do this is to provide a default value to use when the option is `None`:

```
let get default xo =
    match xo with
    | None -> default
    | Some x -> x

# get "none" (Some "abc");;
- : string = "abc"
# get "none" None;;
- : string = "none"
#
```

Comment: thanks, but how does List.filter convert opt values to string values? Could you provide an example :D ?

Comment: `List.filter` does no converting, it just selects. But `List.map` does converting (but does not select). That's why you need to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

```
type opt = Some of string | None

List.fold_left (fun lres -> function
    (name,Some value) -> value::lres
  | (name,None)       -> lres
) [] [("s1",None);("s2",Some "s2bis")]
```

result:

```
- : string list = ["s2bis"]
```

Comment: This reverses the order compared to the argument list, so if the user doesn't expect that, you should apply `List.rev` to the result of the fold.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution. (To be honest, even not knowing OCaml this looks at least vaguely decent on its own, but someone did flag it….)

Comment: First of all  novalain, have to told if this code is good or not.